# MongoDB is giving error 'Database not Defined'

Tags: python, database, mongodb, backend

```
import pymongo

import uuid

import datetime


class Database:

    def __init__(self,myclient,mydb,mycol):
        self.blog_id = input('Enter Blog ID : ')
        self.title = input('Enter Title : ')
        self.content = input('Enter Content : ')
        self.author = input('Enter Your Name : ')
        self.created_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        self.ids=uuid.uuid4().hex

    def json(self):
        return {
            'id':self.ids,
            'blog_id':self.blog_id,
            'author':self.author,
            'content':self.content,
            'title':self.title,
            'created_date':self.created_date
            }

    def insert(self,data):
        mydb.mycol.insert_one(data)


myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")

mydb = myclient["mydatabase"]

mycol = mydb["posts"]

dataBase = Database(myclient,mydb,mycol)

data = dataBase.json()

dataBase.insert(data)
```

When I go to MongoDB and try using the

```
databaseName.collectionName.find({})
```

command, it says

```
E QUERY    [js] ReferenceError: mydatabase is not defined : @(shell):1:1
```

Comment: you have to use `use databaseName` then use `db.collectionName.find({})`

Comment: i did that , It didn't work , It isn't even working in mongodb

Comment: what error you get when you run `db.collectionName.find({})` and does you get error when you run `use databaseName`

Comment: I don't get any error when I use ' use database' and The Error Whenever I use any command in mongoDB , It has the same error , I even tried manually entering Data through mongoDB server , It's the same error 'database is not defined'

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Studio3T](https://studio3t.com/).

This is a client application for mongoDB which enables users to play around db easily.